# Parallel diagonal lines on background

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to draw **2 parallel diagonal lines on the background of my div**.
Please see my table [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2e5cL0dc/1/):

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/TnPgXl4.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 40px;
}
#table {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

**I want to achieve something like this:**

[image: Div with 2 diagonal lines on background]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the **2 diagonal lines** with a rotated pseudo element. The 2 lines are the top and bottom borders of the absolutely positioned pseudo element:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/TnPgXl4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 40px;
}
#table {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px; height: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#table:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%; bottom: 100%;
  height: 20px; width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

This is how this works :

- the width between the 2 lines is controled by the height of the pseudo element
- the thickness of the lines is controled by the border-width
- the slant of the lines is controled by the rotation angle
- the overflowing parts of the lines are hidden with the `overflow:hidden;` property on the div

Note that you need to add vendor prefixes to the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) properties for browser support and you probably don't need the vendor prefixes on the `background-size` property:

- [canIuse for background-size](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)
- [canIuse for 2D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: Thanks for great and expanded answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `:after` and `:before` pseudo elemnts and [`trasform: rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding:40px;
}

#table {
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#table:before, #table:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 60%;
  height: 102%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}

#table:after {
  left: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful too!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to wek-tiki and Nenad Vracar's answers would be to use the `skewX()` CSS transform.

This solution won't require you to hide anything that overflows the edge and therefore adds a little more flexibility.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/TnPgXl4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 40px;
}
#table {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
#table:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Wow great! Which browsers this method support?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d all 2d transform should be supported right back to IE9 (with a prefix) and on all modern browsers.

Comment: So If I'll use exactly this code without any change, this all supported on all browsers?

Comment: @WebR pretty much. Ofcourse you always want to confirm it yourself by running tests. web-tiki's answer will work to as thats also a 2d transform.

Answer (score 3):

## Svg

You could use an svg element and span the svg to your div.

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 20px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.container svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <line stroke="white" x1="47" x2="57" y1="100" y2="0" />
    <line stroke="white" x1="57" x2="67" y1="100" y2="0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```